# publish project to server through ftp

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am going to build my project using gulp and upload the built program to a testing server through ftp. Once testing pass, I need to upload the version to a production server. Everything is done primitively.

However, if the number of project increase, it will be quite difficult to handle all of them.

What I want to do is develop a simple program which allow me to transfer a folder of whole files to a server.

I want the program is decided in nodejs hence i can add my own security mechanism. It should be better if the program can merge with gulp.

Can someone give me some suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any servers now or you need suggestion for servers too?

Comment: I have window and linux (centos)

Comment: To add ftp-functionality to your `gulp` tasks, try using [`vinyl-ftp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-ftp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am going to build my project using gulp and upload the built program to a testing server through ftp. [...] I want the program is decided in nodejs hence i can add my own security mechanism.

First of all, if you're using ftp then you can forget about security mechanisms. The FTP protocol is inherently insecure and you should not use it for anything, especially for critical things like this.

You should be using scp, rsync or git for things like that instead, as is usually done.

Now, what you're trying to do here is reinventing a CI system when there are a lot of such systems readily available, from systems that you host yourself like Jenkins, to systems that are hosted for you like Travis or Circle. Some of them offer free service.

They can integrate well with Gulp, they can get all of your changes from GitHub or other git repo, test everything for you and even deploy the code to production servers when the tests pass.

Those are very complicated systems that are hard to do right and handling the source code is security critical. First I would evaluate the following tools and services and only if none of them suits your needs I would consider developing a custom tool for that.

Some tools and services that you can use:

- Jenkins
- Travis CI
- Circle CI
- Codeship
- GitLab CI

More tools:

- http://www.yegor256.com/2014/10/05/ten-hosted-continuous-integration-services.html
- https://www.slant.co/topics/186/~best-hosted-continuous-integration-services

Comment: thanks for suggestions, I will try and find the most suitable one.